# Group by: return '3' instead of 3 rows for example

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

For a school assignment I have to "*give an ordered overview by product of the number of salesman that've sold that product.*"

I have three columns: `VerkoperNr` (Salesman ID), `ProductNr` (Product ID) and `Aantal` (Amount)

---

Database:

[image: The database]

My query: `SELECT ProductNr, COUNT(VerkoperNr) FROM Omzet GROUP BY ProductNr, VerkoperNr`. This returns:

[image: Result]

However I don't need the number of times a salesman sells a product, I need to know how many salesman sold that particular product. So `ProductNumber 16386`should have `COUNT(VerkoperNr) of 3`, instead of returning 3 rows (each row is how many times a salesman sold that product)

---

**In short:**
I need a query to return 3 instead of three rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just want to `GROUP BY ProductNr`, not `GROUP BY ProductNr, VerkoperNr`. Otherwise your query is fine.

Comment: Thanks it worked! Can you explain the difference? (Had to change `COUNT(VerkoperNr)` to `COUNT(DISTINCT VerkoperNr` too btw)

Comment: when you group by two different things, you get one row for every different combination of those two things — that is, you get an additional row if the product *or* the salesman is different.

Answer (score 1):

You will get `ProductNumber 16386 with COUNT(VerkoperNr) of 3`
[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bf05d/1)

```
SELECT DISTINCT(ProductNr), COUNT(VerkoperNr) FROM Omzet GROUP BY VerkoperNr
```

This should also work :

```
SELECT VerkoperNr, count(ProductNr) 
FROM table_name GROUP BY VerkoperNr
```

[SQL Fiffle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bf05d/4)

Comment: thanks for your answer, however `16386` is `6` but should be `3`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this indeeds works and solved my mistake. I just had to change VerkoperNr to ProductNr and vice versa, because I need the exact opposite :)